# Mongoid update_attributes not persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm running an `update_attributes` command to **add** two new added fields in one of my user documents in my rails console and it says `true` on the command being ran, but nothing is persisting in the database.

User.last (simplified):

```
#<User _id: 4c77d555b1382g539f000022, first_name: "Jason", last_name: "Johnson">
```

Commands I tried running (following the http://mongoid.org docs):

```
User.last.update_attributes(nickname: 'Josh', email: 'josh@gmail.com')
User.last.update_attribute(:nickname, 'Josh') # I get a NoMethodError: undefined method `update_attribute'
```

user.rb

```
  field :first_name
  field :last_name
  field :nickname # just added this
  field :email # just added this
```

mongoid gem version:

```
rails (3.0.3)
mongoid (2.0.0.beta.20)
```

Comment: Is there are reason you're running a beta version of Mongoid 2.0.0? The current (stable) version is 2.4.10.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you had an empty users collection when you got the NoMethodError.
The following works for Rails 3.2.3, Mongoid 2.4.10.
I suggest copying and running the test so that you have a known environment for each thing that you are testing.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name
  field :last_name
  field :nickname
  field :email
end
```

test/unit/user_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    User.delete_all
  end

  test "update_attribute" do
    User.create(first_name: 'Jason', last_name: 'Johnson')
    assert_equal(1, User.count)
    p User.last
    User.last.update_attribute(:nickname, 'Josh')
    p User.last
    User.last.update_attributes(nickname: 'Josh', email: 'josh@gmail.com')
    p User.last
  end
end
```

test output

```
Run options: --name=test_update_attribute

# Running tests:

#<User _id: 4fc63ff5e4d30b08ca000001, _type: nil, first_name: "Jason", last_name: "Johnson", nickname: nil, email: nil>
#<User _id: 4fc63ff5e4d30b08ca000001, _type: nil, first_name: "Jason", last_name: "Johnson", nickname: "Josh", email: nil>
#<User _id: 4fc63ff5e4d30b08ca000001, _type: nil, first_name: "Jason", last_name: "Johnson", nickname: "Josh", email: "josh@gmail.com">
.

Finished tests in 0.019296s, 51.8242 tests/s, 51.8242 assertions/s.
```

Comment: if i try update_attributes(:_type => "ClassName") then its not working...but its working fine with update_attribute(:_type,"ClassName").